# Need Help: Selecting Subset of RTKQ Data Based on Slice State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm facing a challenge where multiple components in my application require access to a subset of data retrieved from a common query. This subset is determined by user selections, which are stored in a Redux slice.

The issue I'm encountering is efficiently fetching and utilizing only the user-selected portion of data.

Here's my current approach in TypeScript:

```js
function Example() {
  // Using a slice to store selected IDs instead of the full data objects,
  // as the complete data is already available in the cache:
  const selectedDataIds = useAppSelector(selectedDataIds);

  // Fetching all data and then filtering based on the selected IDs:
  const { data } = useGetAllDataQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: result => {
      return result.data.filter(item => selectedDataIds.includes(item.id));
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My concern is the repetition and potential boilerplate this method introduces. If I need to use the selected data in several components, I'll have to import the selected IDs, use the useGetAllDataQuery hook, and apply the selectFromResult filter each time.

I'm considering creating a filterDataByIds function to reduce repetition in the seletFromResult, but I'm worried of adding another thing to remember at every use.

Does anyone have suggestions or a more efficient way to handle this scenario?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions ! :)